# How to give the corresponding distribution function.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

A box contains five keys, only one of which will open a lock. Keys are randomly selected and
tried, one at a time, until the lock is opened (keys that do not work are discarded before another
is tried). Let Y be the number of the trial on which the lock is opened.

Give the corresponding distribution function.

I know that $$F(y) = P(Y < y)$$

$$ for -\infty<y<\infty$$

I also know that the probability function is $\frac15$ for$$ Y= 1,2,3,4,5$$

How do I find the distribution function (or PDF) based on the info given?

Comment: "I also know that..." That is only for $Y=1$, no, as it is without replacement?

Comment: yes without replacement

Comment: What do you mean by "...that is for Y=1,no..."?

Comment: $F(y)=P(Y<y)$ is not correct. It should be $F(y)=P(Y\leq y)$. You cannot find a [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) (probability density function) because there is no such thing here. You must go after a [PMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) (probability mass function) taking values on the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. If $f$ denotes the PMF then $f(i)=P(Y=i)$.

Comment: Ok. So the PDF does not exist because it's not continuous? Also, the PMF would be just the prob distribution of Y?

Comment: Yes. Just find $P(Y=i)$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5$ and you are ready in the sense that you have full information about the distribution. Actually you allready mentioned in your question that $P(Y=i)=\frac15$. If you are after $F$ wich is the CDF then you can easily find it on base of the PMF.